# Facebook Likeview is not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

I have implemented Like as suggested on Facebook developer site 
I just added Likeview and set Object id for post code is as below

```
likeView  = (LikeView)findViewById(R.id.like_view);
    likeView.setObjectId("https://www.facebook.com/karan.raj.5070276/posts/396696657159566");
```

My layout file has LikeView widget

```
<com.facebook.widget.LikeView
    android:id="@+id/like_view"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

On clicking it just opens Dialog for sometime and it disappears without any action
and In log-cat I finds error message like
"Like dialog is only available to developers and tester"
What should I do In my Facebook app. Should I add Roles for developer and tester 
Please help any help will be appreciated

Comment: Unless your app has been approved for Like Dialog use, that feature will only be available for Admin/Developer/Testers of the app. If you want public usage, then you'll have to get it approved.

Comment: @MingLi what do You mean by that? I have to get approved so my app can use Like button? How is it done?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be approved before it can be used publicly. Follow the steps here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#submitlogin and in Step 2, scroll to the bottom for Native Like Button.

Answer (score 4):

Login your facebook with same user which you have created facebook app with. This error appeared because you logged in facebook with other user.

**Note:** By default Facebook app app is in development mode and can only be used by app admins, developers and testers.